# Opera transforms HTML5 input with type="email" when UTF-8 char occurs

Tags: html, validation, email, cross-browser

In Opera, when I write `xxx@ů.cz` into input with `type="email"` and alert it in JavaScript, it yells `xxx@xn--3ga.cz`, but e.g. in Firefox it yells `xxx@ů.cz`.

Wikipedia says the hostname can have UTF-8 chars. Why this happens? How can I get then the original input on server side?

My pages are UTF-8 encoded.

> You can try this issue here too: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_email

Answer (score 0):

xxx@xn--3ga.cz is perfect. It is the punycode version. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode

It should have better support than the original version entered by the user. But if you want, you can transform from punycode to utf-8